# With jQuery Mobile, how can I create a radio list with a checkbox look-and-feel?

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I need to create a radio list with jQuery Mobile, but the UI mock-ups use check boxes on the right side to identify the selected option, rather than the SAT-circle selection that radio lists usually have.

I am thinking that the best way is to create the list as a [select list](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/checkboxes/), and then use custom jQuery javascript to disable all other options when some option is selected.

Is this the best way to do it?  Should I try to use a radio list and then restyle it with CSS instead?  I am not sure how easy it would be to go the CSS route, I would rather not have to override anything in the jQuery javascript or CSS files...

Thanks,

KG

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've seen this page? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/forms/radiobuttons/

It seems like they are rendering standard radio buttons that behave in the expected radio button style.

Here's a screen shot from the page linked above:
[image: Radio Button]

If you're looking for a list, literally structured in `<ul>` or `<ol>` with `<li>`'s you should look here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-forms.html

Comment: I have certainly seen this page.  This post is entitled, "With jQuery Mobile, how can I create a radio list with a checkbox look-and-feel?"  I want little checkbox icons for my radio list, not the radio circle icons that it normally comes with, as seen on that page.